# pod file and framework file are in red color

Tags: ios, swift, installation, cocoapods

i don't know why but some of files are in red colour i followed all steps for install pod

[image]

[image]

[image]

i tried to reinstall but it's same still files are in red colour

as you can see i installed Alamofire library in my project
when i run below code in viewDidLoad

```
    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").response { (response) in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```

this is my pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Application Giggy' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Application Giggy

pod 'Alamofire'


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247240/discussion-between-heli-bhadeshiya-and-muhammad-hasan-irshad).